# circular reference on linux

Tags: java, spring

There is a circular reference in my program. I think there is no problem in my program. It can run on `windows`. When I put it on `linux`, it results in an exception.

Below is the error log:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customGroupDataManager': 
Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?`
```

Below is my code:

```
<bean id="customUserDataManager" lazy-init="true" class="com.hand.hap.activiti.manager.CustomUserDataManager">
    <constructor-arg ref="processEngineConfiguration"/>
</bean>

<bean id="customBehaviorFactory" class="com.hand.hap.activiti.custom.CustomBehaviorFactory"/>

<bean id="activitiBeanProvider" class="com.hand.hap.activiti.custom.ActivitiBeanProvider"/>

<bean id="notificationListener" class="com.hand.hap.activiti.listeners.NotificationListener"/>


<bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
    <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" value="true"/>

    <property name="mailServerHost" value="smtp.126.com"/>
    <property name="mailServerPort" value="25"/>
    <property name="mailServerUsername" value="hap_dev@126.com"/>
    <property name="mailServerPassword" value="hapdev11"/>

    <property name="asyncExecutorActivate" value="true"/>

    <property name="dbIdentityUsed" value="false"/>

    <property name="activityBehaviorFactory" ref="customBehaviorFactory"/>

    <property name="groupDataManager" ref="customGroupDataManager"/>
    <property name="userDataManager" ref="customUserDataManager"/>

    <property name="beans" ref="activitiBeanProvider"/>

    <property name="customDefaultBpmnParseHandlers" >

        <list>
            <bean class="com.hand.hap.activiti.custom.AddListenerUserTaskParseHandler">
                <constructor-arg index="0" value="create"/>
                <constructor-arg index="1" ref="notificationListener"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: when you say it's not the same result on windows and linux, what's the difference ? Do you do it with an IDE on windows and not on linux ? is a jar you satart manually in both case or is it drop in a JEE server as war/ear/jar ? what's your vesrion of spring ?

Answer (score 1):

Yup, there is:

customUserDataManager requires processEngineConfiguration which requires customUserDataManager, and the circle begin.

Comment: i set lazy-init="true" in bean customUserDataManager，i think it  can solve this problem，but it doesnt work. And it cannt run only on

Comment: i set lazy-init="true" in bean customUserDataManager，i think it can solve this problem，but it doesnt work. And it cannt run only on linux

Answer (score 1):

Check the beans `customUserDataManager` and `processEngineConfiguration` you have a constructor reference to  `processEngineConfiguration` in `customUserDataManager` and a property reference to `customUserDataManager` in bean `processEngineConfiguration` so it is certainly a circular reference.

**Update**

Apart from the above circular reference please check the `customGroupDataManager` bean for circular reference.

Comment: i set lazy-init="true" in bean customUserDataManager ，doesnt it work？

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki when I started the answering that answer was not there. it appeared after I clicked submit.

Comment: still I was the first one who answered the question

Comment: @fourthfloor'smdeicine please add the bean definition for `customGroupDataManager`

Comment: @Karthikeyan Vaithilingam please do any edit to your answer, otherwise i can't undo my downvote